# Arraylist to csv export in javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

I would like to make the csv file from the arraylist. So help me to achieve this.

Code Snippet:

```
$('#csvdownloadbutton').click(function () {
    var myArray = new Array();
    myArray.push("string 1");
    myArray.push("string 2");

    //how to export here. based on the myarray
}
```

When I click the button it should be converted to CSV and downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can put array content into form's text area that would be posted on form's submission. By activated post request, you can insert the data into .csv file.

```
$('#csvdownloadbutton').click(function () {
    var form=document.createElement("form");
    form.method="post"; form.action="...path...";
    form.style.display="none";
    var textarea=document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name="csv_content";
    form.appendChild(textarea);

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    var myArray = new Array();
    myArray.push("string 1");
    myArray.push("string 2");

    for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
        textarea.value+=myArray[i]+"\n";
    }
    form.submit();
}
```

Further actions depends on your back end technology.

ajax

```
$('#csvdownloadbutton').click(function () {
    var content="";    
    var myArray = new Array();
    myArray.push("string 1");
    myArray.push("string 2");

    for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
        content+=myArray[i]+"\n";
    }
    $.ajax({
            url:'...path...',
            method:'POST',
            data:{csv_content:content},
            request.done(function(msg){
            $(document).html(msg);
            })
    });
}
```

Comment: When I click the button it should be convert as csv and make to download.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand comment quite clear. You need a server to do conversion and return you ,csv file.